# Passing text value via parameter

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I have a command `Get-WmiObject win32_service|select name, osname|? name -match $a` and `$a=cmd.exe`. Problem is when I pass `$a`, the output has all processes. But when I pass value directly `Get-WmiObject win32_service|select name, osname|? name -match "cmd.exe"` it works good. How it should be passing name of process in variable?

Comment: Set `$a` to equal `"cmd.exe"`. Wrap it in quotes to make it a string.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a WMI call for something that exists as a native PS command?

```
Get-Process | ? Name -eq cmd.exe
```

Comment: Right, but if I try execute that cmdlet: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ip -credential $Credential -scriptblock {Get-WmiObject win32_process |select name, osname|? name -match $a}` on remote host, again there are all process in output.

Comment: @TraPS `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ip -credential $Credential -scriptblock {$a = 'cmd.exe' ;Get-WmiObject win32_process |select name, osname|? name -match $a}`

Comment: Right, but what if I would like to pass to`$a` no only "cmd.exe" but it could be depend of input argument. I mean once `$a` is `"cmd.exe"` next time '"powershell.exe"` etc.